# Stop creating mail message and Followers in perticular model in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When I create new sale order,it also creates the mail messages and followers at bottom of form view.

But I want to make that system should not create mail message and followers while users creates or writes data of "sale.order" model.

How can I stop such message and followers creation .?

Answer (score 3):

Just need to apply context in create and write method of that model.

```py
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    res=super(sale_order,self.with_context({'mail_create_nosubscribe':True,'tracking_disable':True})).create(vals)
    return res

@api.multi 
def write(self,vals):
    res=super(sale_order,self.with_context({'mail_create_nosubscribe':True,'tracking_disable':True})).write(vals)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove it from the view then override the template and remove the fields named:

- message_follower_ids
- message_ids

These two fields are responsible for the view part.

Code to remove the fields:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='message_follower_ids']" position="replace"/>
```

Will this be fine or should I tell you how to update the record at model level?

Comment: But It will just stop showing the Messages in Form View, it will not stop creation, I found the solution.

Comment: Yeah this will only remove the view part of the mail_message.

Also we can override the field structure on model level and achieve the required.

Comment: @MeetVaishnani what is the solution